# Remove duplicate items from array and keep last occurrences - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, duplicates, nsarray

I have an array, as

(one, two, one, two, three, one, three, two)

I want to remove duplicates, and keep last occurrences of items only. my result array should be:

(one, three, two)

I achieved removing duplicates by `[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array]`  but this keeps first occurrences of items. the result it gives is (one, two, three) i.e. 1st index, 2nd index and 5th index.

How can I keep last occurrences only, so my result should be 6th index, 7th index, and 8th index?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to process an existing array or would it make more sense to update the array to the end result as you add items to it?

Comment: Use a reverse enumerator, process for duplicates and then re-reverse the processed array.

Comment: @rmaddy either would work.

Comment: Create the ordered set on the reversed array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the right direction @Avi and @Cristik (commenters on the question) , implemented the following solution and its working:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[originalArray count]];
NSEnumerator *enumerator = [originalArray reverseObjectEnumerator];

for (id element in enumerator) 
{
   [array addObject:element];
}

NSOrderedSet *orderedSet =  [NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:array];

/* orderedSet now has has the desired result */
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@implementation NSArray (Extended)

- (NSArray *)arrayByRemovingDuplicatesMaintainingOrder
{
    NSMutableSet *arrayObjects = [NSMutableSet set];
    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (id obj in self)
    {
        if (![arrayObjects containsObject:obj])
        {
            [result addObject:obj];
            [arrayObjects addObject:obj];
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't give the required result.